# Problem with Pascal - Fatal: Syntax error, "identifier" expected but "in" found

Tags: parameters, procedure, pascal

```
procedure LoesungBestimmen (
            in a,b,c : real;
            out Loesung1, Loesung2 : real;
            out gibtLoesung : boolean);
{ bestimmt die Loesungen der Gleichung
a*x*x + b*x + c = 0.0
unter der Vorbedingung: a<>0.0 }

    var
    d : real; {Hilfsvariable}
    
begin
    d := b * b - 4.0 * a * c;
    if (d < 0.0) or (a = 0.0) then
        { nicht loesbar oder Vorbedingung nicht erfuellt }
        gibtLoesung := false
    else
    begin
    gibtLoesung := true;
    d := sqrt (d);
    Loesung1 := - (b - d) / (2.0 * a);
    Loesung1 := - (b + d) / (2.0 * a)
    end
end; { Loesung bestimmen }
```

the program does not accept the in-command nor the out-command in the parameterlist of the procedure?!

Comment: What Pascal compiler are you using? What do you expect "in" and "out" to do?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin `in` is probably meant to read `protected` – a read-only value – since there are no assignments to `a`/`b`/`c` in the `procedure` definition. `Protected` is only available in processors supporting this Extended Pascal (ISO standard 10206) feature. Delphi and the FreePascal Compiler have the non-standard parameter kind `const` similar to EP’s `protected`. `out` is probably meant to be a “write-only parameter”. Extended Pascal does not provide a facility to indicate such. Delphi and FPC know `out` only as a _compiler hint_, that is for the purposes of optimization.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt - I've seen the IN/OUT usage that the querent is trying to use in other language, but I'm not aware of any Pascal compiler that implements them with those keywords. Normally, Pascal is presumed to pass parameters by value, which effectively makes them all "in" parameters from the point of view of the caller; "out" (writable) parameters are signaled by VAR. The answer by August Karlstrom is consistent with my experience, except for having ever encounted a Pascal compiler that actually implements them (I believe that I've only actually seen it in some BASIC dialects).

Answer (score 2):

In Standard Pascal you cannot use `in` or `out` in formal parameter declarations. However, it should work if you delete `in` and replace `out` with `var`. In some Pascal dialects and Pascal inspired languages `in` is used for variable parameters that can only be read and `out` for variable (result) parameters that can only be written to.

Comment: Well, Pascal _does_ know the word `in`, but it is the membership operator testing membership of an element in a `set`.